# how can I write this module import/promise routine in the least amount of code?

Tags: javascript, promise, systemjs

I'm implementing SystemJS to import external js modules. I'd like to define my module names in a string array and then implement a custom promise routine after all of the modules have been imported. Looking to implement something like this:

```
var modules = 
[
   'MyModule1',
   'MyModule2',
   'MyModule3'
];

$.each(modules, function(i, module)
{
  return SystemJS.import(module + '.js');
})
.then(function(){
  //post import processing
});
```

The code above doesn't work but it demonstrates the basic idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You use `$.each` but haven't tagged jQuery

Comment: Would this help? https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/pull/695

Comment: @evolutionxbox - documentation for the win :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Promise.all

```
Promise.all(modules.map(module=>SystemJS.import(module + '.js'))
.then(function(){
    // all loaded here
});
```

Of course, the documentation for SystemJS shows this exact method - that's what documentation is for

Comment: Unfortunately, using this approach prevents the imported js files from displaying in Chrome Dev Tools - Sources or Network. I tried including the following pragma at the top of one of the js files but the js file still did not get displayed in CDT using this approach:

//# sourceURL=Common.js

Comment: In CDT I tried "Add folder to workspace" and added my js scripts folder to the workspace. Unfortunately, breakpoints in these files are not getting hit. Does the orange color of the folder I added to my CDT workspace mean that it's not included in the loaded js files?

Comment: `prevents the imported js files from displaying` - if the files are retrieved over the network then they should appear in Network at least - do you have **All** selected in Network tab?